# Selenium login to WSJ error of Timeout Exception

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

This is a web scraper for the WSJ. I am using Selenium to log in to the WSJ premium account before having access to the website articles. I am getting an error of TimeoutException when trying to send the password to the password key. It is throwing the error in the end. It gets to the login page, and then it cannot send the keys to the password. I have tried to look at different ways to locate the password.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv

driver  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/years'
user1 = 'USERNAME'
pass1 = 'PASSWORD'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(user1)

continueWithPassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='button'][@class='solid-button continue-submit new-design']")
continueWithPassword.click()
time.sleep(5)

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
password.send_keys(pass1)


submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='submit'][@class='solid-button basic-login-submit']")
submit_button.click()
```

This below is the full stack trace:

```
/Users/tad/PycharmProjects/WSJScraper/venv/bin/python /Users/tad/PycharmProjects/WSJScraper/main.py
[WDM] - 

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 94.0.4606
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 94.0.4606
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 94.0.4606
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/94.0.4606.61/chromedriver_mac64.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [/Users/tad/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/94.0.4606.61]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tad/PycharmProjects/WSJScraper/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
  File "/Users/tad/PycharmProjects/WSJScraper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @st.huber attached!

Comment: It could be that 5 seconds are not long enough or that your username is not recognized and you actually never get forwarded to the password field